# How to call action method without view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to call a action method in controller. but the actonmethod has no view.

I have this:

```
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">       
        <a href="@Url.Action("GeneratePDFFFromHtml", "Product")" class="btn btn-primary enabled"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i> @Resources.Action.Navigation.GeneratePDF </a>      
    </div>
```

and this is my action method:

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult GeneratePDFFFromHtml(EditProductModel model, string data)
{           
    SubmittedForm sf = new SubmittedForm();
    string schema = requestSchema;
    customer_DbConnection db = new customer_DbConnection();
    RenderFormController renderController = new RenderFormController();
    renderController.GeneratePdf(data, db,sf);
    //return RedirectToAction(model.DesignId, "Prdocut/Edit");
    return Content("It works");           
}
```

Comment: Consider naming it `GeneratePdfFromHtml`.

Comment: Have you tried void?

Comment: `"but the action method has no view"` - Then what *does* it have?  What should be the result of the action?

Comment: Make its return type void if you dont want to return ActionResult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want do to some work based off a button/link, why not just use an ajax call?

For example:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">       
    <button onclick=GeneratePdf('@Model.DesignId', <string data>) class="btn btn-primary enabled"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i> @Resources.Action.Navigation.GeneratePDF </button>      
</div>
```

And in your .cshtml, I would recommend having a Script section at the bottom of the file:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //modify as needed to make it pass in what you need.
        function GeneratePdf(designId, stringData) {
            $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("GeneratePDFFFromHtml","Product")",
            data: { designId: designId, strData: stringData },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                //TODO: Add whatever if you want to pass a notification back
            },
            error: function(error) {
                //TODO: Add some code here for error handling or notifications
            }
        }
    </script>
}
```

Then, in your controller, you can have your function return void. NOTE: I am not really sure if you even need to pass in the DesignId but you have it in there so I will keep it there. You will most-likely need to edit this method some more to make it work properly but hopefully this will get you going.

```
[HttpPost]    
public void GeneratePDFFFromHtml(string designId, string strData)
{           
    SubmittedForm sf = new SubmittedForm();
    string schema = requestSchema;
    customer_DbConnection db = new customer_DbConnection();
    RenderFormController renderController = new RenderFormController();
    renderController.GeneratePdf(strData, db, sf);
    //return RedirectToAction(model.DesignId, "Prdocut/Edit");       
}
```

Also, this will be async so you may want some notification to the user that some action is being done like a spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Try with System.Web.Mvc.EmptyResult or redirecting to same page with
System.Web.Mvc.RedirectResult.

Answer (score 0):

Easier way is to use routing, route attribute with your controller as below.

In your controller simply decide the needed route and add it. I've used *ImportExport*

```
[Area("Exporting")]
[Route("api/ImportExport")]
public class ImportExportController : Controller
{
    ............

    [Route("GeneratePDF")]
        [HttpPost]    
            public void GeneratePDFFFromHtml(string designId, string strData)
            {           
                SubmittedForm sf = new SubmittedForm();
                string schema = requestSchema;
                customer_DbConnection db = new customer_DbConnection();
                RenderFormController renderController = new RenderFormController();
                renderController.GeneratePdf(strData, db, sf);
                //return RedirectToAction(model.DesignId, "Prdocut/Edit");       
            }

    .......
```

And in your cshtml page simply call this path as below

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="~/api/ImportExport/GeneratePDF" id="frmGenerate" novalidate="novalidate" class="form-horizontal">
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Andy Korneyev!!! Your sample code helped me solve something I have been struggling with all day. I used your code (and modified it slightly) to go back after running a code block function without a refresh/view.

```
return Content("<script type='text/javascript'>window.history.back();</script>");
```

I know this is really old but hopefully you see this.